# How to shred .docx XML?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xml

I am trying to import a xml (actually a docx file) to a sql server 2008 database. I am almost a novice in XML programming. I googled a lot but almost all the examples there are with simple xml file. Here the xml file is little complex(please see below). Can you please give me some idea how I should create the table for this XML and what query should I run in sql server. I need values for all the tags e.g. w:rsidP,w:rsidRDefault,w:rsidR of w:p,w:pStyle,w:bookmarkStart,w:t tags etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
<w:body>
<w:p w:rsidR="00EF42E0" w:rsidRDefault="00EF42E0" w:rsidP="00EF42E0">
<w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
</w:pPr><w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_Toc212523610"/>
<w:r>
<w:t>Summary</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="00EF42E0" w:rsidRDefault="00EF42E0" w:rsidP="00EF42E0"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="mainbodytext"/><w:ind w:right="-694"/><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/></w:rPr><w:t>What is the Group Defined Practice for Integrity Management?</w:t></w:r></w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="00EF42E0" w:rsidRDefault="00EF42E0" w:rsidP="00EF42E0"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="mainbodytext"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">This Practice is derived from the GP Group Standard, GRP 01 January 2006, </w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="gramStart"/><w:r><w:t>Integrity</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd"/><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"> Management.  In developing QMS it has been possible to embed much of the content of the IM Standard directly into the Group Essentials statements.  For elements 2, 7, 8 and 9 of the Standard it was possible to do that in their entirety and therefore content of those elements are not repeated within this Practice.</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:body></w:document>
```

Answer (score 10):

When working with XML in SQL Server you use the [xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and when shredding XML documents you typicly use the `nodes()` and `value()` methods. The XML you have here also include a number of namespaces so you have to specify the ones you need using [WITH XMLNAMESPACES (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

The XML is quite complex so without knowing how you want the data extracted I can only give you a couple of sample queries that you then can modify to whatever it is you need.

You have four `w:p` nodes and here is a query that fetches the attributes from those nodes. Using `@` specifies that it is the value of an attribute you want-

```
with xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' as w)
select P.X.value('@w:rsidR', 'char(8)') as rsidR,
       P.X.value('@w:rsidRDefault', 'char(8)') as rsidRDefault,
       P.X.value('@w:rsidP', 'char(8)') as rsidP
from @doc.nodes('/w:document/w:body/w:p') as P(X);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13593)

If you in addition to that want the text in the `w:t` node you need to do a `cross apply` to a second `nodes()` clause that will shred the XML within the `w:p` node.

```
with xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' as w)
select P.X.value('@w:rsidR', 'char(8)') as rsidR,
       P.X.value('@w:rsidRDefault', 'char(8)') as rsidRDefault,
       P.X.value('@w:rsidP', 'char(8)') as rsidP,
       T.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Text
from @doc.nodes('/w:document/w:body/w:p') as P(X)
  cross apply P.X.nodes('w:r/w:t') as T(X);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13594)

You said in your question that you want to get the values from all the tags. I don't know how useful this is to you but you can build a Name-Value list with all the attributes and elements in the XML.

This will give you all elements.

```
select T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') Name,
       T.X.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') Value
from @doc.nodes('//*') as T(X)
```

Change `'//*'` to `'//@*'` and you will get all attributes.

```
select T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') Name,
       T.X.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') Value
from @doc.nodes('//@*') as T(X)
```

And you can combine them in one query as well.

```
select T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') Name,
       T.X.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') Value
from @doc.nodes('//@*, //*') as T(X)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13595)